# using this keyword in angular in nested functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Hi I would know how can I use variables of the component in nested function.

Here's an example:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = ['Angular 6','Angular5','Angular4','Angular2'];
  isexist: string[]=[];

ifExist(text){
  var that= this;
  console.log("first ",this);
  var test="test";
  let exist= this.name.map(function (elm){
    if(elm==text) {
      console.log(this);
      this.isexist.push(elm); // works with that.isexist.push(elm); 
      }
      })
}
ngOnInit() {
  this.ifExist('Angular 6');

}
```

Here's what I get in browser dev tool

```
first  AppComponent {name: Array(4), namev: "helo", isexist: Array(1)};
second undefined
```

I have some questions 
How can I access to `isexist` without using arrow funtion  ?
why the second `this` does not contain `test` element ?

Answer (score 2):

try lambda here:

```
ifExist(text){
  var that= this;
  console.log("first ",this);
  var test="test";
  let exist= this.name.map((elm)=>{
    if(elm==text) {
      console.log(this);
      this.isexist.push(elm); // works with that.isexist.push(elm); 
      }
      })
}
```

Comment: Yes with arrow function that works ;) but I have mentioned it , how get the same result before `=>` was out ?

Comment: that is because of a javascript concept called closures. In javascript each function is an object. before arrow in html 5 we had to use bind function. [bind link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: Read this https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20%26%20closures/ch5.md

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you cannot access to `ifExists` without using arrow functions is that `this` in an arrow function has the same value as the context in which the arrow function was *created*.

`this` in a normal anonymous function however, has the value of the context in which the normal function was *called from* ( In your case, the context and scope of normal function is only the inside of `ifExists` method.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason at all to loop, as you're only checking if an array contains an element. You don't even return from `map()`. The other answers already explain your problem with `this`, and here's how you should refactor your code (rewrote to plain js to make it work in the snippet, but you get the idea):

```js
class Foo {
  constructor() {
     this.name = ['Angular 6','Angular5','Angular4','Angular2'];
     this.isexist = [];
  }
  
  ifExist(text) {
    if (this.name.includes(text)) this.isexist.push(text);
  }
  
  runner() {
    this.ifExist('Angular 6');
    console.log(this.isexist);
  }
}


new Foo().runner()
```